Links placed in footer of my Website created in wordpress appear black without choosing it
So I created a website and placed some navigation links such as Social media profiles , Faq etc. And only one of them is being shown in white . (And no I havent selected black color for the remaining.)Also the color black appears only in view page. When I edit the page it the colors are back to normal.
I tried to edit the color and it says that white is selected
